# Python to combine and match keys in dictionary on flask template

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x, flask

I am calling two API endpoints which returns the following

```
api1 = [
{
    "size": "SMUS",
    "price": "0.02"
},
{
    "size": "LGUK",
    "price": "0.0045"
},
{
    "size": "SMUK",
    "price": "0.0018"
},
{
    "size": "LGUS",
    "price": "0.05260"
},
{
    "size": "XLUK",
    "price": "0.00299"
},
{
    "size": "XLUS",
    "price": "0.060"
}]


api2 = {
"r1": 176,
"r2": 125,
"r3": 0,
"stock": [
    {
        "stamp": "LG",
        "free": "472",
        "return": "0"
    },
    {
        "asset": "MD",
        "free": "238",
        "return": "0"
    },
            {
        "asset": "SM",
        "free": "47",
        "return": "0"
    },
    {
        "asset": "XL",
        "free": "6880",
        "return": "0"
    }
],
"view": [
    "HIGH"
]}
```

Now I am trying to get the data into a table. I am using Flask templates, so i have the table on my home.html file with the following code for the table body.

```
<tbody>
{% for data2 in api2['stock'] %}
    {% for data1 in api1 %}
        {% if data2['stamp'] in (data1['size'])[:-2].strip() %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ data2.stamp }}</td>
                <td>{{ data2.free }}</td>
                <td>{{ data1['price'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I am not getting an error, however when the table renders it displays many rows of 'stamp' data and the data is all messed up.
I would like the table to provide --- stamp - free - price

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

In home.html, change;

```
data2.stamp to data2["stamp"]
```

and same with data2.free

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't understand as there's no "data" so I cannot replace "data2" with "data" or am I missing something

Comment: Oh sorry that is data2. You don't have to change data2 .

Comment: I tried that but it didn't solve my problem... The table still is not being formatted correctly with the data.